# What is this dishwasher symbol?

Tags: dishwasher

I have an Amica dishwasher. I don't know the exact model and couldn't find it. A few days ago, I started having an issue with it; it wouldn't drain. I cleaned it, put some extra salt, and surprisingly, it worked today. Now, I want to run it without dishes but with an aid kit (like a Cleaning Liquid bottle). However, it does not run properly. It starts but stops after 1 minute, and it keeps beeping. Also, there's a symbol (on the far right) that looks like a clock with three stripes, which keeps flashing.

Do you know what could be the reason?[image]

Comment: Do you know what model your dishwasher is?

Comment: @brhans No, that was the first thing I tried to find

Comment: LMGTFY - https://www.amica-international.co.uk/dishwashers/integrated-dishwashers/ADI651 - whether yours is that model or not I bet the same symbols are used across the range.

Comment: Yep, that clock with the arrow appears to be a rapid cycle.